# Joint Models - Time specification in longitudinal and survival submodels

Tags: mixed-model, survival, panel-data, cox-model, joint-distribution

A quite general question. When I jointly model time to event data and longitudinal process with Joint models, looking at math behind it, it seems to me that the times to event outcomes and times of repeated measurements of longitudinal process have to be "as close as possible" as Survival at time t depends on the whole history of the biomarker up to time t. It this correct? This doubt arises because I've data for biomarker evolution in a time window that is mostly before the time in which events occurs. Does it make sense to use a joint model in this case even though event times often occur later in time than the measurement time window of individual biomarkers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Survival at time t depends on the whole history of the biomarker up to time t. It this correct?

For a Cox or other proportional-hazards model, it depends on how "the whole history of the biomarker" is *encoded in a covariate* at each event time. Such models don't have a built-in memory of past covariate values. The regression is based on the set of covariate values *at each event time*, effectively comparing the values for the individual who has the event against all those still at risk.

That doesn't mean you are stuck with values that you measure at event times. You can, in principle, define covariates that represent cumulative sums of observed covariates, or running averages. For an analogy in laboratory measurements, think about the difference between an instantaneous blood glucose measurement and a hemoglobin A1C value representing a type of average over the prior few months. Anything you define as a covariate (while respecting causality) is OK, but it's only the value as defined at each event time that matters.

Thus predictions from longitudinal models of covariate values can also be used to define covariate values at event times. See Section 5 of the R survival [time-dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf), on "Predictable time-dependent covariates."

Things are trickier with other types of survival models that do depend "on the whole history of the biomarker." For example, in accelerated failure time models, covariates can be thought of as stretching or shrinking the time axis of the survival curve. Thus prior covariate history can contribute to the likelihood.

At some level, your question has merit even with standard survival models that only use baseline covariate values. How sure are you that those baseline values still matter at later event times? Eventually, it comes down to whether the modeling is suitable for its intended purpose. Even if a joint model isn't perfect, it still might perform better than a model that only uses baseline covariate values. You won't know unless you try.